# Storing array in PROGMEM

Tags: arduino-uno, progmem

I have an array of a lot of numbers (1 and 0) but i can't store them since arduino does not have enough space. How can i save an array of example 00110 in PROGMEM, then read from PROGMEM and set x to be equal lets say, third int in the array?

Comment: How many is "a lot", and how wasteful is the datatype you have chosen?

Comment: 4000 elements and each element is a number like 1 or 0 to set a pin high or low.

Comment: Stored as `int` variables (as you seem to suggest) that's a massive 8KB.  Packed into individual bits of a byte that's a mere 500 bytes.

Comment: I can store it in PROGMEM

Comment: The Arduino website tells you all about how to use PROGMEM.  Have you considered reading that? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM

Comment: Yes i didn't understand it well i need a code for my case

Comment: There is suitable code right there on the page for you. What more do you need?

Comment: Can you please send me the part of the code for storing an Array of 1's and 0's and then setting a variable as a value from that array?

Comment: Look at the bits of that code pertaining to the variable "charSet" - it has everything you need.

Comment: It's not about storing array but declaring *const char PROGMEM myarray[50] = {0x45, 0x47};* in source code , etc. It's elementar task appearing in many examples.

Comment: After i store the array in PROGMEM how do i set a variable to have a value of a element inside that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them with `const byte PROGMEM` with bit 0 as MSb and bit 7 as LSb per byte. E.g. 011100100101001010101011 would become `const byte[] var PROGMEM {0x72, 0x52, 0xab}`

Use the following macro to retrieve them (untested):

```
#define loadbit(mem, pos) ((pgm_read_byte(&(mem[pos / 8])) >> (7 - (pos % 8))) & 0x01)
```

So if you had `const byte[] data PROGMEM {0x72, 0x52, 0xab};` you would call `loadbit(data, 3)` and it would return bit 3 starting with 0 on the left, i.e. `1`.

Naturally if you needed more than one bit at a time there are probably situation-specific routines that could be used, but without knowing anything about the actual program the above will work.

Comment: What data type is that? 0x72? Is that hex? And how do i convert big data chunks of binary into that data type?

Comment: 8 bits at a time.

Comment: @Arduino I usually write a Perl or PHP script (depending on what the source of the data is) to convert it into C source code.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in Ignacio's answer, you can pack your bits of data into bytes and access them via `pgm_read_byte()` calls.  If (for coding convenience, not for efficiency) you prefer to pack the bits into larger units, you can use `word` and `dword` access functions, as listed in [AVR pgmspace.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html) documentation.  The `_near` and `_far` suffixes denote 16 or 32 bit pointers, respectively; for an Uno with its 32K flash memory, `_near` is always suitable.  See [PROGMEM documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM) at arduino.cc for further discussion.

Here's an example program that accesses and prints data from program memory in 16-bit chunks:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);         // initialize serial port
}
int k=0;
const uint16_t fnums[] PROGMEM {191, 272, 353, 434, 515, 646, 767, 888};
void loop() {
  uint16_t b = pgm_read_word_near(fnums+k);
  Serial.print(k);  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(b);  Serial.println();
  k = (k+1)%8;
  delay(1000);
}
```

To pack your 4000 bits of data in the first place, write a C or Python program that runs on a host computer and writes out array definitions that you can cut and paste into a sketch.  Here's an example (in Python) that packs bits into bytes:

```
data = [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]

first = 1; byt = 0
for i, b in enumerate(data):
  if i%8==0:
    if first:
       print 'const uint8_t fnums[] PROGMEM {',
       first = 0
    else:
       print '{},'.format(byt),
       byt = 0
  byt = (byt<<1) | b        # add bit into byte being built

print byt<<(8-i%8), '};'
```

Here is what the program produces:

```
const uint8_t fnums[] PROGMEM { 197, 43, 32, 200, 47, 197, 30, 119, 153, 37, 180, 117, 48, 218, 214, 212, 170, 262 };
```

If you want that code to instead pack bits into 16-bit words, change 8 to 16 in four places.  Note, the code stores bits in the “bit 0 as MSb and bit 7 as LSb” order mentioned in Ignacio's answer.  Thus, `data[0]` is stored in the high bit of `fnums[0]`, `data[8]` is stored in the high bit of `fnums[1]` , and so forth.

Comment: The thing is that `(E)LPM` only loads a single byte at a time regardless, so using larger types causes the program to do more work for no gain.

Comment: Yes, I meant to mention that byte access uses fewer instructions.   However, for some kinds of data (not necessarily this data),  coding convenience rather than efficiency may be important.  Added a note to answer.

Comment: How do i convert bits into bytes like in vazquez-abrams example?

Comment: @Arduino, see edit.  Also, upvote answers you find useful

Answer (score 1):

Building on the excellent other answers by jwpat7 and 
Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, you could conceivably convert your bits into a table using Lua:

```lua
data = { 1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,
         0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,
         1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,
         0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,
         0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1 }

output = 0
bit = 0

for _, num in ipairs (data) do
  assert (num == 0 or num == 1, "Number must be 0 or 1")
  output = (output * 2) + num
  bit = bit + 1
  if bit >= 8 then
    io.write (output .. ", ")
    output = 0
    bit = 0
  end -- if
end --for

print ""
```

Output from above:

```
197, 43, 32, 200, 47, 197, 30, 119, 153, 37, 180, 117, 48, 218, 214, 212, 170, 131,
```

Now you can make a simple function to pull a particular bit out of PROGMEM:

```C++
const byte myTable [] PROGMEM = {
  197, 43, 32, 200, 47, 197, 30, 119, 153, 37, 180, 117, 48, 218, 214, 212, 170, 131, 
  };

bool getBit (const unsigned int which)
  {
  const unsigned int whichByte = which / 8;
  const byte whichBit = which & 0x07;
  return bitRead (pgm_read_byte (&myTable [whichByte]), 7 - whichBit);
  }  // end of getBit

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ("Starting");

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (myTable) * 8; i++)
    {
    Serial.print (int (getBit (i)));
    Serial.print (", ");
    }
  Serial.println ();
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  }  // end of loop
```

Output from above:

```
Starting
1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
```